# How to get the text of the selected option using vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to get the text of a selected option input and display it somewhere else. I know how to do it using jQuery but I want to know how can we do it using Vuejs.

Here is how we do in jQuery. I mean the text of Selected Option not the value.

```
var mytext = $("#customerName option:selected").text();
```

Here is my HTML

```
    <select name="customerName" id="">
         <option value="1">Jan</option>
         <option value="2">Doe</option>
         <option value="3">Khan</option>
   </select>

 {{customerName}}
```

Now how can I display the selected option under it. like Jan, Doe, Khan ?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Instead of define the value only as the id, you can bind the selected value with an object with two attributes: value and text.
For example with products:

```
<div id="app">
   <select v-model="selected">
       <option v-for="product in products" v-bind:value="{ id: product.id, text: product.name }">
         {{ product.name }}
       </option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Then you can access to the text through the "value":

```
   <h1>Value:
     {{selected.id}}
   </h1>
   <h1>Text:
     {{selected.text}}
   </h1>
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ay2atz8y)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   selected: '',
    products: [
      {id: 1, name: 'A'},
      {id: 2, name: 'B'},
      {id: 3, name: 'C'}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
   <select v-model="selected">
       <option v-for="product in products" v-bind:value="{ id: product.id, text: product.name }">{{ product.name }}
       </option>
   </select>
   <h1>Value:
   {{selected.id}}
   </h1>
   <h1>Text:
   {{selected.text}}
   </h1>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is just assigning `[object Object]` as the value for me

Answer (score 48):

I had this issue, where I needed to get a data attribute from a selected option, this is how I handled it:

```
<select @change="handleChange">
    <option value="1" data-foo="bar123">Bar</option>
    <option value="2" data-foo="baz456">Baz</option>
    <option value="3" data-foo="fiz789">Fiz</option>
</select>
```

and in the Vue methods:

```
methods: {
    handleChange(e) {
        if(e.target.options.selectedIndex > -1) {
            console.log(e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].dataset.foo)
        }
    }
}
```

But you can change it to get `innerText` or whatever. If you're using jQuery you can `$(e).find(':selected').data('foo')` or `$(e).find(':selected').text()` to be a bit shorter.

If you are binding a model to the select element, it will only return the value (if set) or the contents of the option if there is no value set (like it would on submitting a form).

** EDIT **

I would say that the answer @MrMojoRisin gave is a much more elegant way of solving this.

Answer (score 14):

The below code worked to get the Text from the selected option. I added a **v-on:change** , which calls a function **onChange()** to the select element.

```
methods:{
    onChange: function(e){
        var id = e.target.value;
        var name = e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].text;
        console.log('id ',id );
        console.log('name ',name );
    },


 <select name="customerName" id="" v-on:change="onChangeSite($event)">
         <option value="1">Jan</option>
         <option value="2">Doe</option>
         <option value="3">Khan</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a `customers` list and a selected `customer` on your model, an example like below should work perfect:

```
<select v-model="theCustomer">
    <option :value="customer" v-for="customer in customers">{{customer.name}}</option>
</select>
<h1>{{theCustomer.title}} {{theCustomer.name}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess your values should be in the JS. Then you can easily manipulate it. Simply by adding:

```
data: {
  selected: 0,
  options: ['Jan', 'Doe', 'Khan']
}
```

Your markup will be cleaner:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="option in options" value="{{$index}}">{{option}}</option>
</select>
<br>
<span>Selected: {{options[selected]}}</span>
```

[Here is the update JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfnsLfh5/)

As th1rdey3 pointed out, you might want to use complex data and values couldn't simple be array's indexes. Still you can use and object key instead of the index. [Here is the implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/wojdtzr1/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cohars style or you can use methods too. Data is kept in `options` variable. The `showText` method finds out the selected values text and returns it. One benefit is that you can save the text to another variable e.g. `selectedText`

**HTML:**

```
<div id='app'>
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
      {{ option.text }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <span>Selected: {{ showText(selected) }}</span>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    selectedText: '',
    options: [{
      text: 'One',
      value: 'A'
    }, {
      text: 'Two',
      value: 'B'
    }, {
      text: 'Three',
      value: 'C'
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    showText: function(val) {      
      for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
        if (this.options[i].value === val){
          this.selectedText = this.options[i].text;
          return this.options[i].text;
        }
      }
      return '';
    }
  }
});
```

JSFiddle showing [<kbd>demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/pkyah8wp/)

Comment: It's way simpler to keep the options as a simple array and use the index as the value. Except if the value needs to be a specific text, but I don't see the use case for that.

Comment: you can save the text to another variable if required

Comment: I'm saying this because the showText() methods is useless if you simply use the index. as you can show `{{options(selected)}}` simply

Comment: if your data is complex (e.g. customer code and customer name) then you can't use index.

Comment: Yes sure, that's why I said "Except if the value needs to be a specific text". Still I'ld use a simpler object with the keys being the customer code and the values being the customer name. And use the key to display the informations. Just like that:  https://jsfiddle.net/wojdtzr1/

Comment: point noted. however it is easier to serialize objects to json from server side which have two static fields than having dynamic fields. A little complexity here will simplify many things elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use the following suggestion of MrMojoRisin's

```
v-bind:value="{ id: product.id, text: product.name }"
```

However for me this was resulting in that Object's **toString()** representation being assigned to value, i.e. **[object Object]**

What I did instead in my code was to call **JSON.stringify** on a similar object bound to the value:

```
v-bind:value="JSON.stringify({id: lookup[lookupIdFields[detailsSection]], name: lookup.Name})"
```

Then of course I can convert it back to an object using **JSON.parse** and get the requisite id and name values from the result

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the answers here are a bit too complex, so I'd like to offer an easier solution. I'm only going to use an event handler in the example and leave out things like model binding, etc.

```
<select @change="yourCustomMethod">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Then in your Vue instance:

```
...
methods: {
    yourCustomMethod: function(event) {
        var key = event.target.value, // example: 1
            value = event.target.textContent; // example: One
    }
}
...
```

Comment: This will return all the text options in the entire select, not only the selected one.

Comment: Works perfectly and returns the picked value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the template I access the name of the option like this:

`let option_name = this.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].name`

To do this take this approach to set up your template:

Defined your options in an array like
`[{"name":"Bar","value":1},{"name":"Baz","value":2}]` ... etc

Put your options in the `data` function of the component
`<script>export default {function data(){return { options }}}</script>`

Load the `options` in the template using `v:for`:
 `<option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>`

Use `@change="getOptionName"` on the `select` element:

`<select @change="getOptionName">`

In your `methods` get the name:

`getOptionName(event){ let option_name = this.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].name }`

Note in this case the `object` `options` in `event.target.options` does not have anything to do with your data named `options` ... hopefully that will avoid confusion

So a more advanced approach, but I believe when it is all set up correctly getting the name is not terrible, although It could be easier.

Answer (score 0):

الفترة

اختر الفترة
     {{ period.name }}

```html
<label for="period_id" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">الفترة</label>

<select v-model="form.period_id" id="period_id" class="border-gray-300">
    <option disabled value="">اختر الفترة</option>
    <option v-for="period in periods" :value="period.id" :selected="building.period_id === period.id ? 'selected' : null">
    {{ period.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find it out in the Vue documentation here : http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Select

Using v-model :

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option selected>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
<br>
<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
```

In your case, I guess you should do :

```
<select name="customerName" id="" v-model="selected">
     <option>Jan</option>
     <option>Doe</option>
     <option>Khan</option>
</select>

{{selected}}
```

Here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bqyfzbq2/

Comment: It is selecting the value ( 1, 2,3). I want to display the names

Comment: You example don't have value, that's why it's showing the letter A,B and C. what if we have vaule ?

Comment: I need the values as well