# Is this the correct way to use Vue.JS onChange function?

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js

How can i display my data once i select anything from the mod_accs_Role_ID? example i selected 1 in mod_accs_Role_ID then the role_Name would be display 'Hello' which all the data already stored in database

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
  <label for="mod_accs_Role_ID" class="col-form-label">Role
   <span class="text-danger">*</span>
  </label>
  
  <select class="form-control" name="mod_accs_Role_ID" v-model="selected" v-on:change="onChange">
    <option value="">Select Role</option>
    <option v-for="item in sel_role" :value="item.role_id">{{item.role_Display}}</option>
   </select>
 </div>

 <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label for="role_Name" class="col-form-label">Role Action
      <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>

  <select class="form-control not-editable" name="role_Name" disabled>{{selected}}</select>
</div>
```

JS

```
  var vm = new Vue({

            el: '#maint_module_ctrl',
            data: {
                list_MyInfo: [],
                sel_role: [],
                selected:""
            },
            created: function () {
                this.doList();
            },
            mounted: function () {
                $(".bt-table").bootstrapTable();


                var dropdownMenu;
                $('.bt-table').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                    dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');
                    $('body').append(dropdownMenu.detach());
                    var eOffset = $(e.target).offset();
                    dropdownMenu.css({
                        'display': 'block',
                        'top': eOffset.top + $(e.target).outerHeight(),
                        'left': eOffset.left
                    });
                });
                $('.bt-table').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                    $(e.target).append(dropdownMenu.detach());
                    dropdownMenu.hide();
                });



            },
            methods: {

                onChange: function () {
                    var self = this
                    ajaxJsonProcess("get", apiPath + "/param/role-dropdown", "", function (inDat) {
                        self.sel_role = inDat;
                    }, dftError);
                },
```

On Change function not getting any value

Comment: why is your JS code snippet uncomplete? Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & always try to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Alex done improve the edit

Answer (score 0):

Please first bind the drop down first on component life cycle hook created.
Then @OnChange you will get Id of select option. By using Id you can find name of select item.

> let selectName=self.sel_role.filter(role => role.role_id.(selected)
> !== -1).role_Display;

Comment: hmm can i have an example of it?

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46395952/7327166 this is another way to achieve the same