# How to use select box option in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have implemented select box in vue like this:

```html
<select name="count" @change="change($event)">
  <option value="a">one</option>
  <option value="b">two</option>
  <option value="c">three</option>
</select>
```

I know that if you want to get the selected value from the script, you can receive the event and do `event.target.value`.

How can I get one,two,three values ​​instead of a,b,c values?

Comment: Does this answer your question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748162/how-to-get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-using-vuejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text from the selected option like so,

```
  methods:{
    change: function(e){
        var id = e.target.value;
        var name = e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].text;
        console.log('id ',id );
        console.log('name ',name );
    },


<select name="count" @change="change($event)">
   <option value="a">one</option>
   <option value="b">two</option>
   <option value="c">three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<select>` uses the `<option>` *label* (the inner text) as the value if the `<option>` has no `value` attribute, so you could just remove the `value` binding:

```html
<select name="count" @change="change($event)">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-option-label-as-value?file=src/App.vue)